# Need help displaying a list to a user and getting their response using Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, joptionpane

This is the second part of a presentation that I am working on.

```
String temp;

// Create the class
Hello helloUser = new Hello();

//Get the users name
temp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name?");
helloUser.setName(temp);

String hello = helloUser.name(helloUser.getName());

//Greet the user
temp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, hello, "Feeling", 
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, new Object[]{
            "Great", "Good", "Been Better"
        });
helloUser.setFeeling(temp);
```

After I get the users name I want the program to greet them and ask how they are doing, then provide them a selection to choose from for the answer. The code above for greeting the user keeps giving me this error:

`no suitable method found for showInputDialog(<null>,String,String,int,<null>,Object[]) method JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Component,Object,String,int,Icon,Object[],Object) is   not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)`

I would like to give the user a list to  choose from and store their selection in temp. Can I do that with JOptionPane? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current parameter list does not fit any of the overloaded `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` methods provided.

If you provide the `selectionValues` parameter, you must also provide `initialValue`.

Try this instead:

```
Object[] options = {"Great", "Good", "Been Better"};
temp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                                   hello, 
                                   "Feeling", 
                                   JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
                                   null,  
                                   options, 
                                   options[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are forgeting on parameter. From [JOptionPane API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html):

showInputDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message, String title, int messageType, Icon icon, Object[] selectionValues, Object initialSelectionValue)

initialSelection value.

Comment: I fixed this part: 
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, hello, "Feeling", 
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, new Object[]{
            "Great", "Good", "Been Better"
        });
It still gives me an error when I try to assign it to temp. How do I assign the user's selection to temp?

As I was typing a possible solution adding toString() came to mind I'll try that.

Comment: Create the Object array outside the showInputDialog() method and make the initialSelectionValue referenced to the String INSIDE the array. Maybe it is not finding the initial object (besides the same content, these strings are not the same object).

Comment: toString did work. I understood what you meant about the object array. I didn't understand the second part about the String inside the array though.

Comment: "A string" == "A string" is not true because they are not the same objects (even if they have the same content). What I meant is exactly Jason Braucht answer.